# How to export flow to external website

Tags: visual-workflow, cors, lightning-web-components, lightning-scheduler

I am trying to use flow in my local as mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=ls_expose_flow_on_website.htm&type=5)

This is how the code looks like:
[image]

And I'm getting this CORS issue:
***Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://casesrnd-dev-ed.lightning.force.com//runtime_appointmentbooking/Guest_Flow/undefined.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.***

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I did tried with Community URL as mentioned in the document and faced CORS issue even there

Comment: You can Try adding "http://localhost:3001" to your CORS setting in salesforce from Setup->CORS also put http before it

Answer (score 1):

Answer is pretty simple and it was so stupid of me.
I can't white list localhost.

I simply deployed this to Heroku and white listed the Heroku URL and bang.
It worked like charm.